# R data frame - row number increases

Tags: r, dataframe

Assuming we have a data frame (the third column is a date column) that contains observations of irregular events starting from Jan 2000 to Oct 2011. The goal is to choose those rows of the data frame that contain observations between two dates

```
start<-"2005/09/30"
end<-"2011/01/31"
```

The original data frame contains about 21 000 rows. We can verify this using
`length(df_original$date_column)`.

We now create a new data frame that contains dates newer than the start date:

```
df_new<-df_original[df_original$date_column>start,]
```

If I check the length using `length(df_new$date_column)` it shows about 13 000 for the length.

Now we create another data frame applying the second criterion (smaller than end date):

```
df_new2<-df_new[df_new$date_column<end,]
```

If I check again the length using `length(df_new2$date_column)` it shows about 19 000 counts for the length.

How is it possible that by applying a second criterion on the new data frame `df_new` the number of rows increases? The `df_new` should have a number of rows equal or below the 13 000.

The data frame is quite large such that I cannot post it here. Maybe someone can provide a reason under which circumstances this behavior occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example works fine for me:

```
df_original = data.frame(date_column = seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), Sys.Date(), by=1), value = 1)

start = as.Date('2005/09/30')
end   = as.Date('2011/01/31')

df_new = df_original[df_original$date_column>start,]

df_new2 = df_new[df_new$date_column<end,]
```

```
> dim(df_original)
[1] 4316    2
> dim(df_new)
[1] 2216    2
> dim(df_new2)
[1] 1948    2
```

Without seeing an example of your actual data, I would suggest 2 things to look out for:

1. Make sure your dates are coded as dates.
2. Make sure you aren't accidentally indexing by row name. This is a common culprit for the behavior you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the dim command, it's very useful and saves a lot of typing. The strange behavior was caused by a simple typo in df_new2 = df_new[df_new$date_column<end,] where in the code I'm working with was the statement: df_new2 = df_original[...]. The date column in the data frame is of class 'Date'. Also I found insightful: the selection works with your explicit 'as.Date' statement, which stores start and end in 'Date' format. Interestingly it also works with start<-"yyyy/mm/dd" which stores the value as 'character'. For programming I would prefer your explicit date formatting though.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the results you want via one subset command?

```
df_new <- df_original[with(df_original, date_column>start & date_column<end),]
# or
df_new <- subset(df_original, date_column>start & date_column<end)
```

Comment: Dear Joshua, thanks for your answer. I tried both of your methods. The work nicely and produce identical results. They even work, if I define the variables start and end as character.

Answer (score 1):

can you give us `dput(head(df_original))`? which shares with us the first 5 records and their data structure. I am suspicious something is up with the format of your `date_column`.

If you are storing `start` and `end` both as strings (which your example seems to indicate) and the date column is also a string, then you will not be able to use `<` or `>` to compare values of dates. So somewhere you need to validate that everything being compared is known by R to be dates.

Comment: True about needing dput output but I think you're wrong about how `<` and `>` work with character, JD. If ones dates are "character" and in the yyyy-mm-dd format then `<` and `>` will work perfectly well. Try it. (There will be no sensibility checking however.) "2000-01-01" < "2000-02-01" & "2000-01-01" >"1999-01-01"
[1] TRUE

Comment: Good point @DWin. When the dates are formatted as YYYYMMDD you are exactly correct.

Comment: Dear James, thanks for your reply. Due to restrictions I have to follow I actually can't provide a (dput(head(df_original)) but I can describe the output in general terms. It is quite large and starts with structure(list(Var_1=c(..then there follow 6 instead of 5 examples... For the Date column it shows: class = "Date".